# Module isomorphic to its dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be a left $R$-module. What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $M$ to be isomorphic to $M^{\lor}$?

Comment: Being free of finite rank is sufficient. For finitely generated modules over a PID, it is also necessary. In general, I'm not sure if you can do much better. There are non-free projective modules for which this works (e.g. $R$ as an $R\times S$-module for two rings $R,S$), but also non-free projective modules for which this fails (e.g. $(3,1+\sqrt{-14})$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$-module; there are lots of similar examples coming from algebraic number theory).

Comment: Is it sufficient if the module is finitely generated and projective?

Comment: Judging by the counter-example in my previous comment, no.

Comment: But aren't finitely generated projective modules locally free? If this is the case, can't one localize by ideals and work on a local basis (since "being an isomorphism" is a local property)?

Comment: Yes, they are (f.g. isn't even necessary for this). However, I don't see what map you would want to test for being an isomorphism locally. There is no natural map $M\rightarrow M^{\lor}$. You can find an isomorphism $M_{\mathfrak{p}}\rightarrow M_{\mathfrak{p}}^{\lor}$ for each prime $\mathfrak{p}$, but nothing guarantees you can choose these isomorphisms in a consistent manner, let alone so that they are all induced from some map $M\rightarrow M^{\lor}$. The counter-example shows this is in general impossible.

Comment: Note that this is in stark contrast with the double dual, where there is a natural map $M\rightarrow M^{\lor\lor}$. For finite rank free modules, this is an isomorphism and f.g. projective modules are locally free of finite rank and also f.p. so that localization commutes with dualization, so the argument works in this case and shows they are in fact isomorphic to their double duals via the natural map (so-called reflexive modules).

Comment: I see. Thanks for your comments!